# Formal semantics of a mutable/imperative stack

Tags: semantics, stacks, hoare-logic, imperative-programming, persistent-data-structure

When introducing formal semantics for data structures, immutable stacks are a nice simple example :

- $\mathit{is\_empty}(\mathit{create()})=\mathrm{True}$
- $\mathit{is\_empty}(\mathit{push}(e, s))=\mathrm{False}$
- $\mathit{top}(\mathit{push}(e, s)) = e$
- $\mathit{pop}(\mathit{push}(e, s)) = s$

I am trying to do the same for a mutable stack structure, where the $\mathit{push}$ and $\mathit{pop}$ operations will modify a stack instead of returning one.

The way I am trying to do it is with Hoare triples. I can define the simplest ones (omitting that $s$ is a stack and $e$ an element) :

- $[]\  s\gets create() \ [\mathit{is\_empty}(s) \text{ yields True}]$
- $[]\ \mathit{push}(e, s) \ [\mathit{is\_empty}(s) \text{ yields False}]$

However I am not finding satisfactory axioms for $\mathit{pop}$. I could do $$[\mathit{is\_empty}(s) \text{ yields some value } b]\ \mathit{push}(e, s)\mathord{;} \mathit{pop}(s)\ [\mathit{is\_empty}(s) \text{ yields the same value } b]$$.

But this is formally only applicable when one would push and immediately pop, which is too restrictive.

With the immutable version, the same axiom (mutatis mutandis : sequence vs. composition) is acceptable because in any actual $\mathit{pop}(s)$ where $s$ is an expression that correctly denotes a non-empty stack, this expression $s$ can be reduced (in the sense of rewriting) to a normal form $\mathit{push}(\cdot, \cdot)$ and the axiom will then apply, allowing for further reduction.

This does not seem to work in the mutable/imperative case. **Or does it ?**

A solution would be to use properties that express the length of a stack~: pushing adds one, poping subtracts one, and expressing emptiness becomes easy. But this would not be sufficient for tracking the values of the elements ; applying the same idea would amount to having a whole immutable stack in the Hoare properties to track the mutable stack in the imperative program.

**Is there a neater approach to this ?**

Comment: You probably need a way to track the full contents of the stack in our Hoare triples. It should be possible to write in your pre-post-conditions things like "the n-th pushed value is even for each n > 10". You should be able to prove $[s=(s_0,\ldots,s_n)]\ push(e,s)\ [s=(s_0,\ldots,s_n,e)]$ with your Hoare rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing it with specialists, a standard approach would be to denote the state of the mutable stack with an immutable stack in the Hoare triples.

E.g. :

- $[]\  s\gets create() \ [s = \mathtt{[]}]$
- $[s = \mathtt{SomeStack}]\ push(e, s) \ [s = \mathtt{e\mathbin{::}SomeStack}]$
- $[s = \mathtt{[]}]\ b\gets is\_empty(s)\ [ b = \text{True} ]$
- $[s = \mathtt{\_\mathbin{::}\_}]\ b\gets is\_empty(s)\ [ b = \text{False} ]$
- $[s = \mathtt{h\mathbin{::}t}]\ x\gets pop(s)\ [ x = h, s = \mathtt{t} ]$

This is rather cumbersome, but it works. In a sense, it is not very different from what we do with variables in general, except that there are more than one way to change the value of a variable.

Things will get nasty if we begin to have alias problems, but this was to be expected ; separation logic is the key there.